# What's the syntax used for sub foo : method { shift->bar(@_) }?

Tags: perl

```
sub foo : method { shift->bar(@_) }
```

What does  `: method` mean here?

I've never used it this way ...

Answer (score 11):

`: method` is [function attribute](http://perldoc.perl.org/attributes.html) description. A subroutine so marked will not trigger the "Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::%s" warning.

**From [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)'s comment**:

> The warning happens when the sub has the same name as a builtin and it is called without & and not as a method call; perl uses the builtin instead but gives a warning. The :method quiets the warning because it clearly indicates the sub was never intended to be called as a non-method anyway.

**Update**

This code just calls method `bar` when `foo` is called:

```
sub foo : method {  ## Mark function as method
    shift->bar(@_)  ## Pass all parameters to bar method of same object
}
```

More details:

- `: method` - Indicates that the referenced subroutine is a method. A subroutine so marked will not trigger the "Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::%s" warning.
- `shift` - gets first parameter from `@_`, which will be `$self`
- `->bar(@_)` - call same class method `bar` with all other parameters

You can read this as:

```
sub foo : method {
    my ($self) = shift @_; 
    return $self->bar(@_);
}
```

Comment: What does `sub foo : method { shift->bar(@_) }` mean as a whole?

Comment: It seems it still works without the `method` attribute,right?

Comment: Yes, in this case it just prevents warning message

Comment: The warning happens when the sub has the same name as a builtin and it is called without `&` and not as a method call; perl uses the builtin instead but gives a warning.  The :method quiets the warning because it clearly indicates the sub was never intended to be called as a non-method anyway.

Comment: Can you give an example that produces the warning,and after adding `:method` it disappears?

Comment: You could also get the same result writing `shift->bar(@_);` as `bar(@_);`